# Workbox Request method 'POST' is unsupported

Tags: service-worker, workbox

I am using the code from this site: https://developers.google.com/web/tools/workbox/modules/workbox-routing

My code is as below:

```
workbox.routing.registerRoute(
  new RegExp('http://localhost:64445.*/'),
  workbox.strategies.staleWhileRevalidate({
    cacheName:'Post-Run-time-cache'
  }),
  'POST'
);
```

And it gives me the error:

```
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Request method 'POST' is unsupported
```

I do not know what went wrong. It is from the document but it is not supported?? why. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The Cache Storage API doesn't support using a `Request` object whose `method` is not `'GET'` as a cache key. Attempting to store a `'POST'` request in the cache (which is happening under the hood in the `staleWhileRevalidate` strategy) will fail with an error similar to what you're seeing—though I think there's a more informative error logged when you're in Workbox's development mode, on `localhost`.

If you're looking to retry failed `'POST'` requests, I'd recommend the [`workbox-background-sync` module](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/workbox/modules/workbox-background-sync).

Comment: Yes. I did use  workbox-background-sync module and it works! thanks!

Comment: Can you tell how to match PUT, PATCH requests?

Comment: If I use `networkOnly` strategy for a culprit URL domain then the service worker should not try to cache that, right?

Comment: Ref https://gitlab.com/MrCsabaToth/mrcsabatoth.gitlab.io/-/issues/26